# Finding the next result when none is found?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am attempting to traverse a hierarchy with a CTE and it works fine in one scenario but not another and that is where I am stuck.

Given the query;

```
;WITH BOMcte (ID, Code, BomName , ProductID, ProductCode, ProductName , ParentAssemblyID )
AS
(
    SELECT   b.id,
             b.code,
             b.name,
             p.id,
             p.default_code,
             p.name_template,
             b.bom_id
    FROM mrp_bom AS b
    INNER JOIN product_product p on b .product_id = p.id    
    WHERE b. bom_id IS NULL 
    and b.id = @AssemblyID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   b.id,
             b.code,
             b.name,
             p.id,
             p.default_code,
             p.name_template,
             b.bom_id
    FROM mrp_bom AS b
    INNER JOIN product_product p on b .product_id = p.ID    
    INNER JOIN BOMcte AS cte ON b.bom_id = cte.ID    
)
SELECT BoM.* FROM BOMcte BoM
```

The query works just as I expected because the BoM drills down to the child boms on the column bom_id.

In code (from OpenERP) when a child BoM isn't found, (no bom_id) a child product is searched for based on the product_id:

```
sids = bom_obj.search(cr, uid, [('bom_id','=',False),('product_id','=',bom.product_id.id)])
```

I am wondering if there is a method I can use to accomplish the same thing in SQL. Once the CTE doesn't return rows, check with the product_id and a null bom_id. I had thought about another recursive member but I don't think that's what I am looking for.

I know my question probably isn't very clear but, any suggestions?

SQL Fiddle example data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9052/1

Answer (score 1):

The reason why trying the following as HABO suggested `on b.bom_id = cte.ID or ( b.bom_id is NULL and b.product_id = cte.product_id )` and you already tried doesn't work is because it never logically terminates.

However you do have a terminating expression which is do it once when no children are found. The easiest way to that is to add a UNION which checks to make sure that a row in BOMcte has no child

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BOMcte bc WHERE b.id =  bc.PARENTASSEMBLYID)
```

Full SQL

```
;WITH BOMcte (ID, Code, BomName , ProductID, ProductCode, ProductName , ParentAssemblyID )
AS
(
    SELECT   b.id,
             b.code,
             b.name,
             p.id,
             p.default_code,
             p.name_template,
             b.bom_id

    FROM mrp_bom AS b
    INNER JOIN product_product p on b .product_id = p.id    
    WHERE b. bom_id IS NULL 
    and b.id = @AssemblyID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   b.id,
             b.code,
             b.name,
             p.id,
             p.default_code,
             p.name_template,
             b.bom_id
    FROM mrp_bom AS b
    INNER JOIN product_product p on b .product_id = p.ID    
    INNER JOIN BOMcte AS cte ON b.bom_id = cte.ID    
)
SELECT * FROM BOMcte
UNION 

SELECT   b.id,
             b.code,
             b.name,
             p.id,
             p.default_code,
             p.name_template,
             b.bom_id

    FROM mrp_bom AS b
    INNER JOIN product_product p on b.product_id = p.id 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BOMcte bc WHERE b.id =  bc.PARENTASSEMBLYID)
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9052/31)

Note: It may be possible to encode the terminating expression in the CTE using an incrementing LEVEL value like those found in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) on Recursive Queries

Comment: Not quite; it returns a duplicate child row.

Comment: I suspect I'm wrong with `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mrp_bom mb WHERE mb.bom_id = b.ID ) ` Can you create some sample data. A [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be nice too.

Comment: Does this help you? I haven't used SQL Fiddle before. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9052/1 (edited url)

Comment: That does indeed help. Just to clarify you're desired output is to have 3 rows. The third row would have a parent assembly id of 2348.

Comment: My desired output would have 4 or 5 rows. Assembly 2347 -> assembly 2348 -> Assembly 2095, components 2096 and 2097. I say 4 or 5 because 2348 has no components and I am not sure if it would be included in the output. 2095 is the next assembly based on the product_id, which is what I am after. If the parent (that has no children) is included that's fine; I could filter that later.

Comment: @ehcanadian I think I understood what you're asking for. As a side note you might want to edit your question to include the SQL Fiddle so people don't have to look for it in the comments.

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for; in my database the query is returning all my BoMs, not just the ones related to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to do, but something like this for your final join may do it:

```
on b.bom_id = cte.ID or ( b.bom_id is NULL and b.product_id = cte.product_id )
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do and I have tried adding the condition you mentioned but I hit the maxrecursion limit. (It loops on the product id.)

Comment: You can use the [MAXRECURSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) query hint to increase or remove the limit on recursion.  Are you sure that it is not stuck in a cycle, e.g. going back and forth between a BoM and a product?